# Connecting three led transformers

Tags: switches

I'm a furniture maker and I built a unit which used three circuits of led lights.
Each circuit's transformer has a max output of 2.5 A.
I would like to use a single switch to put between the plug and the transformers.
I found a very tiny rocker switch which is rated 250vac 10A.....I guess it's ok but is so small that it makes me paranoid about catching fire or something?
Sorry if its a dumb question!

Comment: Can you add some links to part numbers / datasheets / pictures?

Answer (score 1):

A 250V 10A switch is standard for light switches in those countries that use 230V mains. It should be suitable to put inline on either side of the power supply (which is what you will have for LED lights - in contains a transformer but has other stuff as well).

The voltage on the LED side will be much less than mains voltage and the current on the line side will be much less than 2.5A or even 3x2.5A for all 3

It is likely that the LED voltage will be DC, not AC and, in general switches have a lower current rating for DC than AC and may be unsuitable. If you change your mind and intend to put the switch on the LED side, check the switches DC capacity.